# Write Python Output to File in Cronjob

Tags: linux, cron, python, shell-scripting

I have a script (/home/user/script.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/python /home/user/program.py >> /home/user/logs/out.log &
```

and it is working. The output from the python script is written to the out.log file. Now I am adding the script to cron:

```
*/1 * * * * /home/user/script.sh
```

Restarting cron and nothing is written to the out.log file. Cron is running and executing the script every 1 minute.

Why it's not working?

Comment: Have you checked cron's log file?

Answer (score 0):

The prefered way to do this is to use pythons [logging](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) module and write directly from inside the script instead of redirecting the output.